# How to resolve this type assignment error (from a target function to `observe` )?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, mobx, mobx-react

Here is my code:

```
  import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

  ...

  const Widget = observer(() => conditionA ?
      <MyCustomWidget ... />
      : undefined);
```

Basically the idea is that if `conditionA` is true, I want the `Widget` to be an instance of 
`MyCustomWidget`, otherwise it should be nothing.

However typescript raises this error message:

```
Error:(25, 26) TS2345: Argument of type '() => Element | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IReactComponent<any>'.
  Type '() => Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ClassicComponentClass<any>'.
    Type '() => Element | undefined' provides no match for the signature 'new (props: any, context?: any): ClassicComponent<any, ComponentState>'.
```

If I change `undefined` to `<div />`, then it works.

However it is possible at all to avoid using a `<div/>`?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [type declaration of `React.StatelessComponent`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5f7be1fd628aaa36a1414d6ba59df8ff03ca3f1e/types/react/index.d.ts#L343), `null` is allowed but `undefined` is not, so you can use `null`.  (If `undefined` also works at runtime, you could consider submitting a pull request to the typings to allow it.)